# Continuity problem - bounding $|f(x)|\leq|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a function such that $|f(x)|\leq|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at the origin.

So far, I have that in order for $f$ to be continuous at the origin we need a $\delta$ such that $|x|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)|<\epsilon$, by the definition of continuity. Surely we can simply take $\delta=\epsilon$ in this case and the claimed result follows immediately?

Comment: Surely we can.${}$

Comment: Yes you can. You need to find one value for $\epsilon$ and you found it.

Comment: $|f(x)|\le |x|\Rightarrow f(0)=0$

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in the comments, $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ implies $f(0)=0$. Now let $\varepsilon>0$. Notice that

$$|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)| \leq |x|=|x-0|.$$

Therefore, if $|x|<\delta=\varepsilon$, we obtain that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$. This prove that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.